# How to use the newer version of webpack for the react app (override the webpack config file/ in short get off create-react-app)?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack, create-react-app

I currently want to migrate my app from create-react-app to another framework (where I will manage my own webpack config files for prod, dev, etc). When I ran my project, I got a set of errors :

```
It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.

The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

  "webpack": "4.42.0"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of webpack was detected higher up in the tree:

  /...path/node_modules/webpack (version: 5.27.2) 

Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.

If you would prefer to ignore this check, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That will permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.

To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:

  1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
  2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
  3. Remove "webpack" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
  4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem.
If this has not helped, there are a few other things you can try:

  5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
     This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.

  6. Check if ../path/node_modules/webpack is outside your project directory.
     For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.

  7. Try running npm ls webpack in your project folder.
     This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed webpack.

If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That would permanently disable this preflight check in case you want to proceed anyway.
```

Now, I do not want to reproduce the steps which have been suggested above as I want to "Get Off Create React App", that is use my own webpack config files and other config files as well and also use the latest version of webpack installed.

How do I go about doing this? Do I use `npm run eject` in this case? I am not too sure abt this. Is there some other way of getting off create-react-app or overriding all the config files with our own config file?

Comment: If you're migrating to a different framework or want to use a different webpack version, `eject` is what you're looking for. If you just want to override the configurations, there's projects like [`react-app-rewired`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-rewired) that can help.

Comment: If I use npm run eject on a local branch, is it going to affect my other branches as well? The reason I am asking this is if I mess up something after ejecting, I want to go back to create-react-app. @cbr

Comment: `eject` does not touch your version control, only the files. If it doesn't work, you can just `git checkout -- .` to restore files from the latest commit.